# HashSet showing more values

Tags: java, hashset

```
class KeyMaster {
  public int i;
  public KeyMaster(int i) { this.i = i; }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { return i == ((KeyMaster)o).i; }
  public int hashCode() { return i; }
}


public class MIt 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Set<KeyMaster> set = new HashSet<KeyMaster>();
  KeyMaster k1 = new KeyMaster(1);
  KeyMaster k2 = new KeyMaster(2);
  set.add(k1); 
  set.add(k1);
  set.add(k2); 
  set.add(k2);
  System.out.println(set.size()+":");

  k2.i = 1; // this is creating another object in HashSet
  set.remove(k1);
  System.out.println(set.size()+":");
  set.remove(k2);
  System.out.print(set.size());
}
}
```

I have added two object to the HashSet and have removed it, but in the last s.o.p I still have size 1. I agree I have updated the value of k2 but still I haven't added that to my set.

Comment: is that Java? Did I guess correctly?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, `System.out.println()` gives it away.

Comment: "this is creating another object in HashSet" ... erm, no, it's not. And it's why `set.remove(k2);` doesn't do anything.

Comment: The [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) class doesn't have an `adds` method, static or otherwise. Is that a typo or a compile-time error you've failed to mention?

Comment: @BrianRoach: I think you could use that (a little more verbose, maybe) as his answer.

Comment: You have broken the contract of `HashSet` by mutating the elements inside it. Whatever happens from there is implementation-dependent. The implementation is allowed to throw you an exception, or even erase your hard drive out of spite. ["The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashset uses hashing to store and retrieve the objects. When we add an object in hashmap, JVM looks for the hashcode implentation to decide where to put the object in memory. When we retrieve an object again hashcode is used to get the location of the object.  If you change an object after inserting it into a hashmap, the updated object will have a different hashcode than the originally stored object. As in your case when you update k2.i=1, hashcode for k2 will now be different from original k2 object. So when you call remove with updated k2, JVM actually couldn't find the object and hence not able to delete. Thats the reason why you see the size as 1 in your last s.o.p

Comment: It's a bad idea to change the element under _any_ implementation of Set.

Comment: Adding an additional point, this is the ONLY reason why it is suggested to have immutable objects stored in hashed collections.

Comment: @JunedAhsan, can you please provide reference which mentioned about hashed collection objects need to store as immutable?

Comment: @AlpeshGediya Here you go: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02183/index.html &   http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc for `HashSet.remove()`:

> Removes the specified element from this set if it is present. More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))

You have a line with a comment in your code that says:

```
k2.i = 1; // this is creating another object in HashSet
```

I'm not sure what you think is going on there, but it isn't that.

`k2` is a reference to an object you've put in your `HashSet`. You just changed the value of `i` in that object, which you are using in the overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods. This is a really bad thing to do when you're talking about anything that involves a hash and why you really shouldn't be using mutable objects as keys.

It literally can no longer be found.

`HashSet.remove()` returns a `boolean` - if you were to check that return value, you'd find that it was false.

Comment: ["The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: By the way, does that quote mean that nasal demons are actually possible in Java?

Comment: I'd say ... possibly, yes.

Comment: so u mean to say that as my hashcode is now changed my remove method now cannot find k2.

Comment: @Sunny correct. You are not supposed to change the elements of a set while they are inside the set.

Comment: @Sunny ideally, you shouldn't put anything that _can_ change into a Set or as keys to a Map.

Answer (score 2):

`k2.i = 1;` is not creating another object in HashSet, but it changes k2's hash code. This is why `set.remove(k2);` cannot find and remove k2. If you test `set.remove(k2)` return value you will see false which means that object was not removed.